# error while calc A and B with jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Iam getting error while add A to B with jquery and php

```
$('#add').dblclick(function(){
    var A = $('#A').val();
    var B = $('#B').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            datatype:'html',
            url:'ajax_doadd.php',
            cache:false,
            data:{xa:A,xb:B},
            success:function(data){                                 
                if (isNaN(data)){
                 alert('Some going wrong .. '+ data.length);
                }else{ alert('OK');
                                   }

        }
        });
    }
});
```

ajax.doadd.php

```
$A =  $_POST['xa'];
$B =  $_POST['xb'];

$result = $A+$B;

echo $result;
```

the result apprear not an numeric value

Comment: 1.Change the `dataType` from `HTML` to `text`. 2.use casting in your php file: `echo (int) $result;` (or `float`...)

Comment: if you console.log A and B before the ajax call, do you get the correct values ?

Comment: @ Brewal , yes correct

Answer (score 2):

POST (or GET for that matter) parameters are by default **strings**. You need to convert the POST parameters `$A` and `$B` to *numbers* before you can add them.

For example:

```
$result = floatval($A) + floatval($B);
```

Comment: not working, when I check the result back by isNaN() its apprear not an numeric value

Comment: have you checked the values you are passing to the request?

Comment: for example A = 2, B= 8;  the result  = 10 but when I check the result with isNaN() it apprear not an numeric value

Answer (score 0):

You can simply force the datatype in php
something like
`$result = (int)$A+(int)$B`;//  or float